# When I am using kotlin with Intellij IDEA, MAX_VALUE is considered an unregistered reference

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am following this tutorial to learn the syntax of `Kotlin`, and the guy is using variables to list the `MAX_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE`, and my IDEA is saying they are unregistered references.
Code looks like this:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
println("Hello, world!")
val name = "Will"

var myage = 18

var bigInt: Int.MAX_VALUE
var smallInt: Int.MIN_VALUE
```

The program is stating four errors whenever I hover over them, it says `MAX_VALUE` is an unregistered reference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the error messages on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var bigInt: Int.MAX_VALUE
var smallInt: Int.MIN_VALUE
```

to this:

```
var bigInt = Int.MAX_VALUE
var smallInt = Int.MIN_VALUE
```

The syntax is:

```
var variable: VariableType = valueToAssign
```

However the `: VariableType` part is optional if the type can be inferred from the `valueToAssign`.